# Need help understanding proof of generalised uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was watching this video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgkWUuqoSVM&list=PLdgVBOaXkb9Bv466YnyxslT4gIlSZdtjw&index=9&t=557s about the generalised uncertainty principle when at 09:00 he goes from $$\Delta \hat{A} \Delta \hat{B} =\frac{1}{2}\{\Delta \hat{A}, \Delta \hat{B} \}+\frac{1}{2}[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$$ to $$|\langle \Delta \hat{A}, \Delta \hat{B} \rangle|^2=\frac{1}{4}|\langle[ \hat{A}, \hat{B}]\rangle|^2+\frac{1}{4}|\langle \{\hat{A}, \hat{B} \}\rangle|^2$$ Can someone explain this step to me?

Comment: What does $\langle \Delta \hat{A}, \Delta \hat{B} \rangle$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Write the expectation value of the first equation as $x + i y$, where $x$ is half the expectation value of the anti-commutator and $y$ is half the expectation value of the anti-commutator. Then, the modulus squared of this complex number is simply $x^{2} + y^{2}$, yielding the second equation.